# Getting an "8: Undefined offset: 1" error when re-installing forum mod

Tags: php, smf, simple-machines-forum

To preempt this being marked as a duplicate question, please understand that I have *zero* experience with PHP coding/syntax and I am struggling to apply a general answer to my specific problem.  I think I've figured out where the problem is coming from, but I'm not even 100% about that, so I am seeking the assistance of someone who can help guide me through figuring this out for certain.

We are installing a dice rolling mod to a Simple Machines forum.  The first install went smoothly, no problems.  We wanted to change some of the mod's formatting, so we uninstalled it, changed the files, and reinstalled it.  After reinstallation, posting new topics or make replies resulted in a .  When we disabled the mod, we could reply and post new topics as usual.

After some hunting, we found this in our error log;

```
http://irate-pirate.org/forums/index.php?action=admin;area=packages;get;sa=browse;server=1;relative=posting  
8: Undefined offset: 1  
File: /home4/iratepir/public_html/forums/Sources/Subs-Package.php  
Line: 1503
```

We found the Subs-Package.php file, and here is the surrounding code:

```
1501      // Build an array of parts.
1502        $versions[$id] = array(
1503             'major' => (int) $parts[1],
1504             'minor' => !empty($parts[2]) ? (int) $parts[2] : 0,
1505             'patch' => !empty($parts[3]) ? (int) $parts[3] : 0,
1506             'type' => empty($parts[4]) ? 'stable' : $parts[4],
1507             'type_major' => !empty($parts[6]) ? (int) $parts[5] : 0,
1508             'type_minor' => !empty($parts[6]) ? (int) $parts[6] : 0,
1509             'dev' => !empty($parts[7]),
1510        );
1511   }
```

So, after looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef), I think(???) need to add:

```
//isset()
$value = isset($array['my_index']) ? $array['my_index'] : '';
//array_key_exists()
$value = array_key_exists('my_index', $array) ? $array['my_index'] : '';
```

to the code I've found in the Subs-Package.php file. I'm guessing that I add this before the line the error was found in.

I'm also guessing some of these variables need to be changed to match the parts from our code, but I don't know which variables.

Any help would be absolutely fantastic, and I hope I've given enough information!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `$parts` array indexes are set or not. It can happen that the array `$parts` does not exists. So, you need to add `isset` to handle such cases.

For e.g.

```
1501      // Build an array of parts.
1502        $versions[$id] = array(
1503             'major' => isset($parts[1]) ?(int) $parts[1] : 0,
1504             'minor' => isset($parts[2]) ?(int) $parts[2] : 0,
1505             'patch' => isset($parts[3]) ?(int) $parts[3] : 0,
1506             'type' => isset($parts[4]) ?(int) $parts[4] : 0,
1507             'type_major' => isset($parts[5]) ?(int) $parts[5] : 0,
1508             'type_minor' => isset($parts[6]) ?(int) $parts[6] : 0,
1509             'dev' => isset($parts[7]) ?(int) $parts[7] : 0,
1510        );
1511   }


isset() will check if the referenced value is defined or not. 
empty($parts[index]) can give error in cases where array $parts is not defined 
as it will try to check the value that doesn't exists.
```

This code will work even if `$parts` array is not defined.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I changed my code to match yours, but it did not solve the problem.  When I reinstalled the (unchanged) mod, it broke the reply and new post functions again.  Looks like it's throwing the same error.

Comment: I cleared the error log to get a fresh log, and now I'm thinking that this error was completely unrelated to the mod not working.  Thank you so much for your help--fixing this likely will prevent other errors!